# Multiple look-aheads in a regular expression Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have to check in a string a positive match for a pattern (pattern C) and negative match for pattern A and pattern B. How can I do that in a single regular expression?

If pattern C is there then neither pattern A nor pattern B should be there in the string.

Please assist me with a code snippet. Following code is not working on 5.8.5 and 5.10.1

```
open(FH, "file");
while(<FH>){
    print if(/(?!PATTERN A)(?!PATTERN B)(?=PATTERN C)/);
}
close FH;
```

Comment: Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles. Use 3-arg open, not 2-arg open. Check the result of `open` for errors.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single regular expression? It would be trivial with three separate matches.

Comment: Please note that you are using lookaheads, not lookbehinds.

Comment: @melpomene - All the regular expressions are in a conf file. And the code just picks up reg exes from the conf file and match them for each line. If I change the code all the other reg exec will stop working.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - Lookbehinds will not help my cause at all here.

Comment: @MohitSingh - I was just pointing out that you used the term "lookbehind" in your title.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how you write the pattern..

The pattern should always be preceded with `.*?` or `.*`

So,You can write

```
(?!.*?PATTERN A)(?!.*?PATTERN B)(?=.*?PATTERN C)
```

Comment: Why `.*?` instead of just `.*`?

Comment: @melpomene to avoid matching further..else `.*` would try to match further..it's just a negligible optimization i guess..

Comment: I'd recommend anchoring those lookaheads to the beginning of input as 'ABC' would pass even though, as I understand it, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ No, `.*` would not try to match further once it's found a match. If anything I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Well, if we're going for a *correct* answer, you need both a `^` anchor and the `/s` flag.

Comment: The pattern would match 'C' in 'ABC'.

Comment: @melpomene `.*` eats as much as it wants till the last possible match..so if there are two similar patterns in the text `.*` would match till the last pattern not till first pattern..but this is rare to happen..that's y i said negligible optimization

Comment: Not quite. `.*` is _greedy_. That means it will eat **everything**, then backtrack until the last match is found. This means that for the best case scenario (the match being right at the end), it is slightly worse (it eats the match, then backtracks to the start of the match). For the worst case (the match being right at the start), it backtracks all the way to the start, taking _twice_ as long as `.*?`! cc @melpomene

Comment: @robinCTS That just means `.*` will search from the right, while `.*?` will search from the left.

Comment: Not quite, but I was also wrong. It doesn't quite take twice as long. `.*` starts from the left and eats chars one at a time until it gets to the right, and then starts backtracking whilst searching. This eating occurs faster than the searching. Optimizations in the engine might even do as you say and jump straight to the right, in which case you would be right. Right? :)

Comment: @melpomene you answered it right just one thing... I can't use modifiers, it will change the code, I can't change the code(explained above). @Some.*DJ you are right about your point about .* but here we have to keep in mind that we are talking about lookaheads. So friends my final regx looked something like this "^(?!.*Pattern A)(?!.*Pattern B)(?=.*Pattern C)". Thank you all for showing interest.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the environment requires it there is no need for a fancy regular expression. All you need is

```
print if /PATTERN A/ and not (/PATTERN B/ or /PATTERN C/);
```

Comment: Buddy I have to do it in one regular exp. I have explained above why? Thanks for showing interest.